# How would I take the first "n" elements of a byte array and convert them directly into a string?

Tags: java, string, byte, arrays

I have an array of bytes consisting of 1024 elements. I want to break this down into different string private members (e.g. first 9 bytes for name, next 12 bytes for userID, etc.).

Without having to turn the entire byte array into a string and then using a substring method, is there any way I can turn a range of bytes in the array directly into a private member for my class?

E.g.

```
myObject.name = byteArr[0-9];
myObject.userId = byteArr[10-21];
```

Comment: reading the docs can be pretty helpfull sometimes -.- . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
String myField = new String(myArray, start, end);
```

where `start` would be 0 if you want to start from the beginning

Answer (score 9):

Use `String` constructor:

```
public String(byte bytes[], int offset, int length, Charset charset)
```

Example:

```
myObject.name = new String(byteArr, 0, 10, Charset.defaultCharset())
```

Remember that bytes and chars are different types in Java and you should specify correct conversion using `Charset` class to avoid unexpected results.