# Additional Characters Being Written To File From Client To Server

Tags: java, networking, client-server, buffer, filewriter

I am sending text between a client and server with Java. This is done by sending a byte stream from the client to the server. The string that was converted from the byte stream is then saved to a timestamped folder whereby it is written to a file. Unfortunately, white-space as well as unexpected characters such as "^@" is being written to the file along with the expected text.

What could be the problem for this? I think might be a buffer to string conversion error but I may be wrong.

I have attached run-time output from terminal as well as all the useful code where I believe the problem is occurring. An explanation for this problem rather than just an answer would be most beneficial as I would like to learn why such an error occur.

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  startServer();


  String date = createDateString(); 
  String miniDate = createMiniDateString(); 

  System.out.println("hello, we are still waiting to start...");


  try {
    Socket       connection;
    OutputStream tx;
    InputStream  rx;

    connection = server_.accept(); // waits for connection
    tx = connection.getOutputStream();
    rx = connection.getInputStream();
    server_.close(); // no need to wait now

    System.out.println("We are here now");

    System.out.println("New connection ... " +
        connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() + ":" +
        connection.getPort());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize_];
    int b = 0;
    while (b < 1) {
      Thread.sleep(sleepTime_);

      buffer = new byte[bufferSize_];
      b = rx.read(buffer);
    }

    if (b > 0) {

      //I believe the problem might be due to buffer to string conversion
      String s = new String(buffer); //this is the message, we might have to store it in an array instead?
      System.out.println("Received " + b + " bytes --> " + s);

      System.out.println("***** this is the string: *****"+s);

      System.out.println("Sending " + b + " bytes");
      tx.write(buffer, 0, b); // send data back to client

      createDirectory(s, date, miniDate);

      connection.close(); // finished
    }


  }

  catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // no incoming data - just ignore
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Interrupted Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IO Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

The createDirectory method:

```
public static void createDirectory(String s, String date, String miniDate){


  String dirName = new String(date);//time1
  String fileName = new String(miniDate); //time2
  String text = new String(s); //message

  File dir = new File(dirName); //copy these raw at first and then clean it up as a new method

  if (dir.exists()) {
    System.out.println("++ File already exists: " + dirName);
    //System.exit(0);
  }

  if (dir.mkdir()) {
    System.out.println("++ Created directory: " + dirName);
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("++ Failed to create directory: " + dirName);
    //System.exit(0);
  }

  fileName = dirName + File.separator + fileName;
  File file = new File(fileName);

  if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("++ File already exists: " + fileName);
    //System.exit(0);
  }

  try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    fw.write(text);
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException - write(): " + e.getMessage());
  }

  System.out.println("++ Wrote \"" + text + "\" to file: " + fileName);

}
```

[Output to file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lohm.png)

[Client-side communications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzm3b.png)

[Server-side terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vuCt.png)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to convert to String the whole buffer (all `bufferSize_` bytes), but only first `b` bytes of the buffer contain data received from client. Use

```
String s = new String(buffer, 0, b);
```

to convert only first `b` bytes of byte array (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782300/how-would-i-take-the-first-n-elements-of-a-byte-array-and-convert-them-directl/29782387))